# Trying to implement an image in pySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Im trying to make some sort of pokemon helper where you write a pokemon and the helper gives you a list of pokemon that are strong against the pokemon you wrote. I want to put an image of a pokeball in the GUI but Im having issues putting an image to the right of the listbox.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd

pokemon_data = pd.read_csv('pokemon/pokemondata.csv')

sg.theme("DarkRed2")
layout = [[sg.Text('What poemon are you against'), sg.InputText()],
          [sg.Button('Enter'), sg.Button('Exit')],
          [sg.Text('Pokemon-tips:')],
          [sg.Listbox(values=[], size=(30, 10), key='pokemon_listbox')]]

window = sg.Window('Pokemon Helper', layout)


    pokemon_name = pokemon_name.lower()

    
    user_pokemon = pokemon_data[pokemon_data['Name'].str.lower() == pokemon_name]

    
    if user_pokemon.empty:
        return ['Ingen matchande Pokemon hittades.']

   
    user_type = user_pokemon['Type 1'].values[0]

    
    weak_to = []
    if user_type == 'Normal':
        weak_to = ['Fighting']
    elif user_type == 'Fire':
        weak_to = ['Water', 'Ground', 'Rock']
    elif user_type == 'Water':
        weak_to = ['Grass', 'Electric']
    elif user_type == 'Grass':
        weak_to = ['Fire', 'Ice', 'Poison', 'Flying', 'Bug']
    elif user_type == 'Electric':
        weak_to = ['Ground']
    elif user_type == 'Ice':
        weak_to = ['Fire', 'Fighting', 'Rock', 'Steel']
    elif user_type == 'Fighting':
        weak_to = ['Flying', 'Psychic', 'Fairy']
    elif user_type == 'Poison':
        weak_to = ['Ground', 'Psychic']
    elif user_type == 'Ground':
        weak_to = ['Water', 'Grass', 'Ice']
    elif user_type == 'Flying':
        weak_to = ['Electric', 'Ice', 'Rock']
    elif user_type == 'Psychic':
        weak_to = ['Bug', 'Ghost', 'Dark']
    elif user_type == 'Bug':
        weak_to = ['Flying', 'Rock', 'Fire']
    elif user_type == 'Rock':
        weak_to = ['Water', 'Grass', 'Fighting', 'Ground', 'Steel']
    elif user_type == 'Ghost':
        weak_to = ['Ghost', 'Dark']
    elif user_type == 'Dragon':
        weak_to = ['Ice', 'Dragon', 'Fairy']
    elif user_type == 'Dark':
        weak_to = ['Fighting', 'Bug', 'Fairy']
    elif user_type == 'Steel':
        weak_to = ['Fire', 'Fighting', 'Ground']
    elif user_type == 'Fairy':
        weak_to = ['Poison', 'Steel']

    
    better_pokemon = pokemon_data[pokemon_data['Type 1'].isin(weak_to)]

    
    better_pokemon = better_pokemon.sort_values(['Attack', 'Defense', 'HP'], ascending=[False, False, False])

    
    return better_pokemon['Name'].values[:5][::-1]

    
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    elif event == 'Enter':
        pokemon_name = values[0]
        pokemon_tips = get_pokemon_tips(pokemon_name)
        window['pokemon_listbox'].update(pokemon_tips)

    window['pokemon_listbox'].update(pokemon_tips)

window.close()
```

When i tried putting the image in the code it would either show up as a small gray box or a huge image when you press enter.

Comment: When the huge image appeared, did you try adjusting the size of it in your code? Aka sg.Image(source, size=(30,30))

Answer (score 0):

IMO, I know nothing about pokeman.

Following code demo my way to show an image in an Image element.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

limit = len(sg.EMOJI_BASE64_LIST)

layout = [
    [sg.Push(), sg.Image(size=(56, 56), background_color='green', key='IMAGE'), sg.Push()],
    [sg.Button('PREV'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('CLEAR'), sg.Button('NEXT')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
index = None

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    elif event in ("PREV", "NEXT", "CLEAR"):

        if event == 'PREV':
            index = limit - 1 if index == None else (index - 1) % limit
        elif event == 'NEXT':
            index = 0 if index == None else (index + 1) % limit
        elif event == 'CLEAR':
            index = None
        if index is None:
            window['IMAGE'].update(data='', size=(56, 56))
        else:
            window['IMAGE'].update(data=sg.EMOJI_BASE64_LIST[index])

window.close()
```